# Equivalence of 4.17 Rudin on $X=[a,b]$ and $X=(a,b)$ - inverse of 1-to-1 continuous function on compact set is continuous

Tags: functions, continuity, compactness, inverse-function

> Theorem $4.17$
> Suppose $f$ is a continuous 1-1 mapping of a compact metric space $X$ onto a metric space $Y$. Then the inverse mapping $f^{-1}$ defined on $Y$ by $$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x (x \in X)$$ is a continuous mapping of $Y$ onto $X$.

I'm interested in the compact sets of $\mathbb R$ of the form $[a,b]$ .

Is the following equivalence true:

> Theorem $4.17$ applied to $X= [a,b]$ $\iff$ theorem $(T)$ $\tag{1}$

Where theorem $(T)$ states as follows:

> Theorem $(T)$
> Suppose $f$ is a continuous 1-1 mapping on $X=(a,b)$ onto a metric space $Y$. Then the inverse mapping $f^{-1}$ defined on $Y$ by $$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x (x \in X)$$ is a continuous mapping of $Y$ onto $X$.

?

Taking the restriction of $f$ to $[a',b']$ (where $a'>a$ and $b'<b$ ) gives $\implies$ of $(1)$. I'm not sure of the other way of the equivalence.

EDIT (reply to Paul Frost's comment):

Here is what I think a "zoom" on $(0,0)$ of the image of the function looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Take
$$F : (-2\pi, 2\pi)\to \mathbb R^2, F(t) = \begin{cases} (\cos t - 1, \sin t) & t \le 0 \\ (1 -\cos t, \sin t) & t \ge 0  \end{cases}$$
The image of $F$ is the union $E$ of two circles with radius $1$ and centers $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$  (a "lying figure eight"). It is easy to verify that $F$ is injective. Thus
$$f : (-2\pi, 2\pi) \xrightarrow{F} E$$
is a continuous bijection. Since $E$ is compact, $f^{-1}$ cannot be continuous (in that case $(-2\pi, 2\pi)$ would be compact).

Comment: I don't think $E$ is compact (I've added an image of what I think $E$ looks like around $(0,0)$ at the bottom of my question). The endpoints of the branch of $E$ as $t$ goes to $2\pi$ or $-2\pi$ are not "closed"-like

Comment: @niobium If $t \to \pm 2\pi$, then $F(t) \to (0,0) = F(0)$. The image of $F$ is the union  of two circles (which are both compact). There are no gaps as in your picture.

Comment: Ok but can't we use theorem $4.17$ on $[c,d]$ included in $(a,b)$ and conclude $f^{-1}$ is continuous on every subset $[c,d]$ and **hence** continuous on $(a,b)$ ?

Comment: @niobium If $f$ is a **real-valued** function, then $f^{-1}$ is indeed continuous. But this is a special case and a new question, you asked for a general metric space $Y$.