# Rudin's theorem $4.17$ adapted to $(a,b)$ (continuity and bijectivity implies continuity of inverse) for which of these reasons the conclusion holds?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, inverse-function

Theorem $4.17$ from Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis:

> Theorem $4.17$
> Suppose $f$ is a continuous 1-1 mapping of a compact metric space $X$ onto a metric space $Y$. Then the inverse mapping $f^{-1}$ defined on $Y$ by $$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x (x \in X)$$ is a continuous mapping of $Y$ onto $X$.

I was told that "on $X=(a,b)$ and for a real-valued function $f$ (and of course for a continuous 1-1 function $f$), the conclusion of the theorem holds (that is to say, $f^{-1}$ is continuous)".

My question is: is this true because

- $f$ is continuous and injective on $(a,b)$, hence stricly monotonous on $(a,b)$ and hence has its inverse continuous

or

- because on every $[c,d]$ included in $(a,b)$ we have, by $4.17$, $f^{-1}$ continuous on $f([c,d])$ **hence** for $f$ defined on $(a,b)$ we have $f^{-1}$ continuous on $f((a,b))$

Or is it true because of both above-mentioned reasons ?

PS: Is the second bullet even true?

Comment: Both bullets are true and "because..." is also true if it means "can be proved using...". Platonistically yours.

Comment: So, that means not only for real-valued function but for any function $(a,b) \mapsto Y$ ($Y$ being a metric space) the assertion holds ? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Have to think but at the moment I doubt it (too nice and unknown to be true). My reasoning with your second bullet was that $f([c,d])$ is of the form $[c',d']$ and each point of $f((a,b))$ belongs to $(c',d')$ for such $c',d'$.

Comment: Paul Frost [told me](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4690959/1021982) (in the comments) that it held only for real-valued functions.

Comment: Oh thank you, fine! not only in the comments but in the answer. So you already knew the (negative) answer. I wonder why you re-asked today.

Comment: Yes I knew. But je ne comprends pas pourquoi ce qui serait vrai pour une fonction réelle ne le serait pas pour une fonction vers un espace metrique quelconque ? It's the same argument (with $[c,d]$ included in $(a,b)$)

Comment: Because the additional argument (that every point in $Y$ has a neighborhood of the form $f([c,d])$) is no longer true. In Paul's example, the origin does not.